# PHP Session with Redis via SSL

Tags: php, session, redis

I need to connect to a managed REDIS with a self-signed certificate. So I need to set verif_peer to false. But how? I tried:

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'redis');
ini_set('session.save_path', 'tls://'.$rUrl['host'].':'.$rUrl['port'].'?auth='.$rUrl['pass'].'&verify_peer=false&verify_peer_name=false');
```

I got:

```
session_start(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed
```

I use the extension redis (phpredis) not predis

How do I tell PHP not to try to verify the peer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `database.php` to add new Redis parameters:

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'context' => [
                'stream' => [
                    'verify_peer' => env('REDIS_SSL_VERIFY_PEER', false),
                    'verify_peer_name' => env('REDIS_SSL_VERIFY_PEER_NAME', false),
                    'stream' => [
                        'verify_peer' => env('REDIS_SSL_VERIFY_PEER', false),
                    ]
                ],
            ],
            'scheme' => 'tls',
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_database_'),
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
            'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tls'),
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer' => env('REDIS_SSL_VERIFY_PEER', false),
                'verify_peer_name' => env('REDIS_SSL_VERIFY_PEER_NAME', false),
            ],
        ],
...
```

References:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-redis#connecting-in-php
- https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/2083